# For-each loop in JDeveloper doesn't map the response at all

Tags: xslt, jdeveloper, bpel

I'm developing a BPEL service using JDeveloper 11.1.1.5.0.

The API's response contains some recurring fields and I'm trying to use a for-each loop to map them with the final web-service's response parameters.

The API's response structure is like this :

```
<Data>
  <Item>
    <F6181_SubsWalletCounter>-1</F6181_SubsWalletCounter>
    <FBalanceExpDate>2013-08-13T00:00:00</FBalanceExpDate>
    <FResetWalletCounterValue>0</FResetWalletCounterValue>
    <FRecurringPeriod>0</FRecurringPeriod>
    <FRecurringRefreshDate>1899-12-30T00:00:00</FRecurringRefreshDate>
    <FRecurringRefreshDay>0</FRecurringRefreshDay>
    <F6150_AccountProfileId>18</F6150_AccountProfileId>
    <FLimit>0</FLimit>
    <F8345_PaymentDebt>0</F8345_PaymentDebt>
    <F9217_MinBalance>0</F9217_MinBalance>
    <F9218_MaxPaymentDebt>-1</F9218_MaxPaymentDebt>
  </Item>

  <Item>
    <F6181_SubsWalletCounter>-1</F6181_SubsWalletCounter>
    <FBalanceExpDate>2013-08-13T00:00:00</FBalanceExpDate>
    <FResetWalletCounterValue>0</FResetWalletCounterValue>
    <FRecurringPeriod>0</FRecurringPeriod>
    <FRecurringRefreshDate>1899-12-30T00:00:00</FRecurringRefreshDate>
    <FRecurringRefreshDay>0</FRecurringRefreshDay>
    <F6150_AccountProfileId>18</F6150_AccountProfileId>
    <FLimit>0</FLimit>
    <F8345_PaymentDebt>0</F8345_PaymentDebt>
    <F9217_MinBalance>0</F9217_MinBalance>
    <F9218_MaxPaymentDebt>-1</F9218_MaxPaymentDebt>
  </Item>
</Data>
```

The `<Item>` element and its sub-elements could repeat multiple times maintaining the exact structure within itself. Out of these sub elements, few are to be mapped with the final response parameters.

The xsl code is :

```
<ns2:responseBody>
  <ns2:balanceInfo>

    <ns2:balance> 
      <xsl:for-each select=
            "/tns:Subscriber_WalletInfo_GetResponse/Data/Item">
        <ns2:wallet>
          <xsl:value-of select="F6091_WalletTypeName"/>
        </ns2:wallet> 
      </xsl:for-each>
      <ns2:expirationDate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="FBalanceExpDate"/>
      </ns2:expirationDate>
      <ns2:balanceAmount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="F9261_Balance"/>
      </ns2:balanceAmount>
      <ns2:unit>
                    <xsl:value-of select="F8341_CurrencyName"/>
      </ns2:unit>
    </ns2:balance>
  </ns2:balanceInfo>
  <ns3:Error>
    <ns3:description>
      <xsl:value-of select="/tns:Subscriber_WalletInfo_GetResponse/ErrorDescription"/>
    </ns3:description>
  </ns3:Error>
</ns2:responseBody>
```

[image]

But the response doesn't get mapped with this xsl. I'm not sure if I've made any syntactical error or if any namespace is missing.

Any kind of guidance would be great!

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure if I've made any syntactical error or if any namespace is missing.*

Right both times, I think.

First, the syntax errors.

If the XML introduced with the words "The xsl code is" is in fact the entire stylesheet, then your first syntactic error is that your stylesheet is not namespace-well-formed:  you have not declared any of the namespace prefixs `ns2`, `ns3`, `xsl`.

Your second syntactic error is at the XSLT level:  the namespace prefix `tns` is also not declared.

Your third syntactic error is that the outermost element does not include any xsl:version attribute.

When I supply dummy namespace declarations for the unbound prefixes (and `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` for the prefix `xsl`) and supply an xsl:version="1.0" attribute on the outermost element, then the stylesheet becomes a legal XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, using the "literal result element as stylesheet" option.

So much for the syntax errors.  When I run the repaired stylesheet on the input you supply, I get output.  Not the output you want, but it's progress:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns2:responseBody xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns2" 
                  xmlns:ns3="http://example.com/ns3" 
                  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/tns">
  <ns2:balanceInfo>
    <ns2:balance>
      <ns2:expirationDate/>
      <ns2:balanceAmount/>
      <ns2:unit/>
    </ns2:balance>
  </ns2:balanceInfo>
  <ns3:Error>
    <ns3:description/>
  </ns3:Error>
</ns2:responseBody>
```

Now the semantic errors, which include but are not limited to a namespace error.

You're not getting any information about your input here, because the `select` expressions in your stylesheet (specifically `/tns:Subscriber_WalletInfo_GetResponse/Data/Item` and `/tns:Subscriber_WalletInfo_GetResponse/ErrorDescription`) aren't matching anything.  Both of these path expressions say, roughly:

1. Start at the root of the document (that's the `/`).
2. The outermost element will be named `Subscriber_WalletInfo_GetResponse`, in the namespace bound to prefix `tns`.
3. Within that element, the second select expression searches for a child named `ErrorDescription` which is not namespace-qualified.  The first expression searches for a child (or:  the set of all children) named `Data`, and then within the Data element(s), the set of all children named `Item`, and evaluates the contents of the for-each instruction once for each of them.  The elements `Item` and `Data` are both expected to be namespace-unqualified.

In the data you show, by contrast, the outermost element is not named `Subscriber_WalletInfo_GetResponse` and is not namespace-qualified.  Naturally, neither select expression doesn't match anything:  they both fail at step 2.